# Run-Time Error 40046: Statement too complex

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a code module using the `InsertLines` method, but am getting the

> Statement too complex Error

My code boils down to this loop:

```
Dim extractorModule As VBComponent
With extractorModule.codeModule
    Dim singItem As codeItem
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(codeItems) To UBound(codeItems)
        singItem = codeItems(i) 'array of private type with .value property
        .InsertLines 5, singItem.value 'write to line 5
    Next i

End With
```

Which loops through an array of custom `codeItems`, and writes their `.value` to a new module with `.InsertLines`

---

`singItem.value` is a base64 encoded string. If it is a short one, 100 characters say, like this string:

```
.code_content = "QXR0cmlidXRlIFZCX05hbWUgPSAic2ltcGxlTW9kdWxlIg0KUHJpdmF0ZSBhIEFzIExvbmcNCg=="
```

no problem. However I want a longer string, this one for example (19000 chars, contains newlines):

```
                .code_content = "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" & _
"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" & _
"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" & _
"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" & _
"LCAiRm9ybWF0dGVkIGZpbmUiDQoNCiAgICAgICAgRGVidWcuUHJpbnQgIm1hZGUgaXQgdG8iDQogICAgICAgIERlYnVnLlByaW50IHMNCiAgICAgICAgdi5JbnNlcnRMaW5lcyBjb2RlSW5zZXJ0UG9pbnQsIHMNCiAgICAgICAgRGVidWcuUHJpbnQgIm1hZGUgaXQgcGFzdCINCicgICAgICAgIC5JbnNlcnRMaW5lcyBjb2RlSW5zZXJ0UG9pbnQsIHByaW50ZihTdHJpbmcoNCwgdmJUYWIpICYgIi5tb2R1bGVfbmFtZSA9ICIiezB9IiIiLCBzaW5nSXRlbS5tb2R1bGVfbmFtZSkNCicgICAgICAgIC5JbnNlcnRMaW5lcyBjb2RlSW5zZXJ0UG9pbnQsIHByaW50ZihTdHJpbmcoNCwgdmJUYWIpICYgIi5leHRlbnNpb24gPSAiInswfSIiIiwgc2luZ0l0ZW0uZXh0ZW5zaW9uKQ0KJw0KJyAgICAgICAgLkluc2VydExpbmVzIGNvZGVJbnNlcnRQb2ludCwgcHJpbnRmKFN0cmluZygzLCB2YlRhYikgJiAiQ2FzZSB7MH0iLCBpdGVtQ291bnQpDQogICAgICAgIGl0ZW1Db3VudCA9IGl0ZW1Db3VudCAtIDENCkRlYnVnLlByaW50ICwgIkluc2VydGVkIGNvZGUgY29udGVudCBmb3IgZmlsZTogIjsgaQ0KICAgIE5leHQgaQ0KDQogICAgRGltIGtpbGxMaW5lIEFzIExvbmcgJ3BsYWNlIGZvciBhZGRpbmcgbGFzdCBiaXQgb2YgY29kZSB0byByZW1vdmUgc2VsZi1leHRyYWN0b3INCicgICAgLkZpbmQgInsx" & _
"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" & _
"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" & _
"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" & _
"amVjdF9hY2Nlc3NpYmxlID0gcHJvamVjdF9hY2Nlc3NpYmxlIEFuZCBFcnIuTnVtYmVyID0gMA0KICAgIEVuZCBXaXRoDQpFbmQgRnVuY3Rpb24NCg0KUHJpdmF0ZSBGdW5jdGlvbiByZWFkQnl0ZXMoZmlsZSBBcyBTdHJpbmcpIEFzIEJ5dGUoKQ0KICBEaW0gaW5TdHJlYW0gQXMgT2JqZWN0DQogICcgQURPREIgc3RyZWFtIG9iamVjdCB1c2VkDQogIFNldCBpblN0cmVhbSA9IENyZWF0ZU9iamVjdCgiQURPREIuU3RyZWFtIikNCiAgJyBvcGVuIHdpdGggbm8gYXJndW1lbnRzIG1ha2VzIHRoZSBzdHJlYW0gYW4gZW1wdHkgY29udGFpbmVyDQogIGluU3RyZWFtLk9wZW4NCiAgaW5TdHJlYW0uVHlwZSA9IFR5cGVCaW5hcnkNCiAgaW5TdHJlYW0uTG9hZEZyb21GaWxlIChmaWxlKQ0KICByZWFkQnl0ZXMgPSBpblN0cmVhbS5SZWFkKCkNCkVuZCBGdW5jdGlvbg0KUHJpdmF0ZSBGdW5jdGlvbiBjaHVua2lmeShCeVZhbCBiYXNlIEFzIFN0cmluZywgT3B0aW9uYWwgQnlWYWwgc3RyaW5nTGVuZ3RoIEFzIExvbmcgPSA5MDApIEFzIFN0cmluZw0KJ3NwbGl0cyBhIHN0cmluZyBhdCBldmVyeSBzdHJpbmdMZW5ndGggY2hhcmFjaHRlcnMgYW5kIGRlbGltaXRzDQonMTAyNCBpcyBtYXggY2hhcnMgaW4gYSBsaW5lDQpjaHVua2lmeSA9IEpvaW4oU3BsaXRTdHJpbmcoYmFzZSwgc3RyaW5nTGVuZ3Ro" & _
"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" & _
"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" & _
"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" & _
"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" & _
"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" & _
"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" & _
"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" & _
"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" & _
"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" & _
"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" & _
"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" & _
"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"
```

According to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/module-insertlines-method-access), linefeed character `vbCrLf` should just make code on separate lines (what I want), so that shouldn't be causing the error.

However the length of string is not the problem either, as if `.value = String(19000,"a")` I have no issues. What's the cause of this error and how do I get around it?

### Update

Something more re-createable:

```
Sub testAdd()
    Dim codeStuff As codeModule
    On Error Resume Next
    Set codeStuff = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule).codeModule
    'check for vbProj access
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Access to VBProject disabled": Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo 0
    'try to add code
    With codeStuff
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 3
            'i = 1 fails for me
            On Error Resume Next
            .InsertLines 1, exampleString(i)     'causes the error
Debug.Print "Case"; i; IIf(Err.Number = 0, " suceeded", " failed with err:" & Err.Number)
            On Error GoTo -1
        Next i
    End With
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove codeStuff.Parent
End Sub

Function exampleString(stringType As Long) As String
    Dim result As String
    Select Case stringType
    Case 1                                       'lots of linefeed
        Dim bit As Long
        For bit = 1 To 19
            result = result & """" & String(1000, "a") & """ & _" & vbCrLf
        Next bit
        result = result & """" & String(1000, "a") & """"
    Case 2                                       'long string
        result = String(20000, "a")
    Case Else                                    'short string
        result = String(100, "a")
    End Select
    exampleString = result
End Function
```

Comment: PS, sorry for posting an error message, but I can't work out what's going on, since writing code-modules means you can't enter debug-mode. Also, the entire contents of those code-blocks is the string I want to write, not just the bit that's formatted as a string.

Comment: Can you put this into a simple, recreatable problem that we can work on?

Comment: Why would you want to have code write code?

Comment: @CallumDA Added some test code, you need to enable access to VBProject for it to work

Comment: @jkpieterse I've made a function which compresses the code from all the files in your project into a single module. You then import this single module into another workbook, and it self-extracts back into the original code modules. Sort of like a zip file so you only have to import one thing rather than many. I'm [putting it online](https://gist.github.com/Greedquest/cd02a7d191bcf2ccf0bf498641d9e161) for others to use

Comment: Sounds ilke an interesting project. But wouldn't is be a lot simpler to just use the plain exported text files? Usually VBA code isn't that much?

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit of "prolonging" lines with `_` at the end, try building your string part by part:

```
.code_content = "first part"
.code_content = .code_content & "second part"
```

Comment: Awww I never would've guessed that! Do you know what the limit is?

Comment: I don't but the statement you wrote is in fact one line ca 18k chars long